# Hosting server shows error in mysql connection in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, c#-4.0

when i am running my asp.net website in my local system (Database connection with phpMyAdmin host server link), it is working fine. But after upload the program to host server panel it gives mysql connection error. I have attached mysql.data.dll using nuget package. Refer the picture.
[image: Error]

Can please suggest the good solution?.

[Local IIS Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moiN3.jpg)
[Host Domain Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCNlQ.jpg)

Please refer the above pictures for errors.

Comment: Do you publish your web application and then deploy it on host? Ensure that bin directory has MySQL.data.dll

Comment: Hi Mohsin thanks for your suggestion. I don't know what is that mean publish. Actually i zipped my project folder and copied to my hosting provider panel inside wwwroot and unzipped the file. The pages whatever is not used the MySQL connection is working but pages whatever is using MySQL connection only have error. Bin folder have MYSQL.data.dll file. i already tried to publish sample project to azure. But i don't know how to publish in MSPControl Hosting provider Panel.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, Sorry. Now i published website first and i copied folder into host. But i got this error. Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_qmcsd3jw'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page. some dll files created automatically in bin folder. That 'App_Web_qmcsd3jw' dll also there in bin folder. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Instead of copying the complete folder, just copy all the files and folders in the published folder and paste them in the website root folder on the server.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, I have copied only published folder. i make it as zip file and copied to my domain host(adtek.com.my/wwwroot/) and unzip the folder. do you mean do i have to copy all the folders and files one by one in wwwroot folder?. Actually same folder i have copied in my local iis and it is working fine. I checked the iis version in server. They replied that with the picture of iis version. That is also same.

Comment: You unzipped the published folder contents inside another folder e.g. `adtek.com.my/wwwroot/folder/` or unzip the contents in `adtek.com.my/wwwroot`? You need to unzip folder contents inside `adtek.com.my/wwwroot` to make it work

Comment: Hi Mohsin, inside the wwwroot already have another website. index.php file and webconfig,config.php files, and lot of folders already available in wwwroot folder. if i copy this folder files directly , will previous one will affect right?

Comment: Yes, but if are creating a new folder inside wwwroot then ensure that your website in IIS is pointing to the folder.

Comment: I have added two more pictures in question. one is my local iis result and another one is host domain result. Actually wwwroot inside always we will copy our publised folder right even in local iis. my published folder name 'AdtekESSPortal_Test'. Inside that folder i have all aspx files and bin folders etc. i expect once i run http://adtek.com.my/AdtekESSPortal_Test/ then my home page will run automatically like Local IIS. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Ok! On your host check that correct .NET Framework version is selected for application pool of AdtekESSPortal. On your localhost, AdtekESSPortal_Test is set up as a sub-application under `Default Website`? If yes, then ensure you have similar setup on host server

Comment: Thank you so much Mohsin. Problem solved. Just now got reply from provider. Actually they convert my AdtekESSPortal_Test directory to an application. Now it is working. In Future if again i replace the folder, Can i have to ask them to convert as application?

Comment: Glad that issue is resolved and I have posted the fix as answer. Yes, converting to application is required as it is a separate application

Comment: Please mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, the application was published and then deployed to host server as a sub-application under Default website.